# Свойство transition - при наведении на элемент и ухода с элемента нету плавности

Tags: css

```
<style>
.but1:hover{
border-bottom: 7px solid #029A06;
transition: all .5s ease;   
}
</style>

<div class="but1"><a href="#">Записаться</a></div>
```

При наведении плавность есть в размере полсекунды, а при уходе с элемента border пропадает мгновенно. Как установить плавность при уходе с элемента?

Comment: Поставь transition на .but1, без hover, должно помочь, если нет - пиши

Comment: так мне нужно появление бордера при наведении на элемент. Если убрать hover - бордер будет статичным

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По дефолту у элемента `border: none;` так же как и с `display: none;` - такое `transition` не понимает. По этому нужно задавать "стартовое значение". Кроме того, как уже написали `transition` если вставлен в псевдокласс `:hover` срабатывает только когда `:hover` "активен".

```css
.but1 {
  border-bottom: 0 solid #029A06;
  transition: all .5s ease;  
}

.but1:hover{
  border-bottom-width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="but1"><a href="#">Записаться</a></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!